# ListCellRenderer not showing desired text

Tags: java, jcombobox, listcellrenderer

I am trying to get only the first item in an ArrayList element to display in a combobox. It has been suggested that using ListCellRenderer would help me to achieve this. I have tried and tried, but am unable to access the necessary getCourseNum() method to show up. My code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CourseCon extends JPanel {

private static JPanel editPanel;
private JComboBox<String> editComboLevel;
private JComboBox editCombo;
private static ArrayList<Course> course = new ArrayList<Course>();

    public CourseCon() {

        Integer[] intArray = new Integer[course.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < course.size(); i++) {
            intArray[i] = new Integer(i);
        }
        editPanel = new JPanel();
        editPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,70));
        editPanel.add(editCombo = new JComboBox(intArray));
        ComboBoxRenderer renderer= new ComboBoxRenderer();
        editCombo.setRenderer(renderer);
        editCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example of Code Snippet");
        JComponent newContentPane = new CourseCon();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.add(editPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,80));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                course.add(new Course("Course-1", "Description-1",
                            1, 2, "Level 1"));
                course.add(new Course("Course-2", "Description-2", 
                            3, 4, "Level 2"));
                createAndShowGUI();
                for(Course item : course)
                    System.out.println(item);
            }
        });
    }
    class ComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel
                   implements ListCellRenderer {
        public ComboBoxRenderer() {
            setOpaque(true);
            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
            setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);
        }

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                                           JList list,
                                           Object value,
                                           int index,
                                           boolean isSelected,
                                           boolean cellHasFocus) {
            int selectedIndex = ((Integer)value).intValue();
            //String course = courseArray[selectedIndex]; 
                //I couldn't get this to work

            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
            } else {
                setBackground(list.getBackground());
                setForeground(list.getForeground());
            }
            //I put this in to test and it does show two times
            //makes me think if I could just access getCourseNum()
            //I'd have it. Correct me if I'm wrong please
            setText("Testing");

            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the class I'm working with:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Course {

    private String courseNum, courseTitle, courseLevel;
    private int courseDur, courseFee;

    Course() {}

    Course(String courseNum, String courseTitle, int courseDur, 
                int courseFee, String courseLevel) {
        this.courseNum = courseNum;
        this.courseTitle = courseTitle;
        this.courseDur = courseDur;
        this.courseFee = courseFee;
        this.courseLevel = courseLevel;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String courseInfo = this.getCourseNum()+ ", "+this.getCourseTitle()+", "
        +this.getCourseDur()+", "+this.getCourseFee()+", "+this.getCourseLevel();
        return courseInfo; 
    }
    public String getCourseNum() {
        return this.courseNum;          
    }
    public String getCourseTitle() {
        return this.courseTitle;
    }
    public int getCourseDur() {
        return this.courseDur;
    }
    public int getCourseFee() {
        return this.courseFee;
    }
    public String getCourseLevel() {
        return this.courseLevel;
    }
    public void setCourseNum(String courseNum) {
        this.courseNum = courseNum;
    }
    public void setCourseTitle(String courseTitle) {
        this.courseTitle = courseTitle; 
    }
    public void setCourseDur(int courseDur) {
        this.courseDur = courseDur; 
    }
    public void setCourseTitle(int courseFee) {
        this.courseFee = courseFee; 
    }
    public void setCourseLevel(String courseLevel) {
        this.courseLevel = courseLevel;
    }
}
```

I've been trying for a couple of days, but I'm swimming in unknown waters here. How can I access the getCourseNum() method so that is the only thing populating the combobox? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
NOTE: I asked a similar question a couple of days ago and it was suggested to me that I revamp my code. This is my new attempt. I'm a beginning student so any and all suggestions are welcome. Cheers

Comment: Add the `Course` objects directly to the combo box instead

Comment: I can do that, but then everything shows in the combobox. Is there a way to limit so that only the courseNum shows?

Comment: `It has been suggested that using ListCellRenderer would help me to achieve this.` - and you were told that is only half of the answer, that just using a renderer will break other functionality of the combo box. `Is there a way to limit so that only the courseNum shows?` - you were given an answer when you asked the same question yesterday. You can easily take the code you were pointed to and make a two line change to the code.

Comment: That's what the `ListCellRenderer` is for, now you have access to the `Course` object via the `value` parameter of the `ListCellRenderer`

Comment: I have tried to implement that. I took the advice to make a separate Course class. I have read the docs and worked with the example, but I'm still not able to achieve the desired results.

Comment: I gave you multiple links to read, one for the Swing tutorial to learn to better strucuture your code and get the basics of how a renderer worked and the second link gave a simple example of a renderer that you could easily customize with a couple of lines of code. I called the renderer a `FooRenderer`, but you would obviously call your yours a `CourseRenderer`.

Comment: I am working on that right now. I'm not giving up. I am trying to implement it within my code. Thank you.

Comment: By the way your restructuring of the code is much better. There is no real need for the ArrayList. You can just add Course objects directly to the combo box using the addItem(...) method.

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience. I'm going to check into how to add the objects directly to the combo box. Would that make the combo box dynamic? Would it automatically update as objects are added, edited or removed? Glad to hear I'm making a little progress on code structure. Cheers

Comment: @Spud All Swing compnents are dynamic to some extent as long as the model supports it. Components are updating by adding/removing elements from the model. The model then tell the view (JComboBox) to repaint itself. In the case of the a JComboBox it contains convenience methods that allow you to add elements to the combo box and it will update the model for you. This is why you should NOT use an ArrayList. Many people will attempt to update the ArrayList think this will update the combo box, which is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add all the `Course`s to the combobox, this will make your life infinitely better and easier in the long run...

```
editPanel.add(editCombo = new JComboBox(course.toArray(new Course[course.size()])));
```

Second, modify you `ComboBoxRenderer` to accept `Course` instead of int...

```
if (value instanceof Course) {
    Course course = (Course) value;
    value = course.getCourseNum();
}
```

Lastly, you might want to consider using extending from `DefaultListCellRenderer` instead of `JLabel` and implementing the `ListCellRenderer`, as it takes care of a whole bunch of important stuff...like selection highlighting....

[image]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CourseCon extends JPanel {

    private static JPanel editPanel;
    private JComboBox<String> editComboLevel;
    private JComboBox editCombo;
    private static ArrayList<Course> course = new ArrayList<Course>();

    public CourseCon() {

        editPanel = new JPanel();
        editPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 70));
        editPanel.add(editCombo = new JComboBox(course.toArray(new Course[course.size()])));
        ComboBoxRenderer renderer = new ComboBoxRenderer();
        editCombo.setRenderer(renderer);
        editCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example of Code Snippet");
        JComponent newContentPane = new CourseCon();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.add(editPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 80));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                course.add(new Course("Course-1", "Description-1",
                        1, 2, "Level 1"));
                course.add(new Course("Course-2", "Description-2",
                        3, 4, "Level 2"));
                createAndShowGUI();
                for (Course item : course) {
                    System.out.println(item);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class ComboBoxRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                JList list,
                Object value,
                int index,
                boolean isSelected,
                boolean cellHasFocus) {

            if (value instanceof Course) {
                Course course = (Course) value;
                value = course.getCourseNum();
            }

            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        }
    }

    public static class Course {

        private String courseNum, courseTitle, courseLevel;
        private int courseDur, courseFee;

        Course() {
        }

        Course(String courseNum, String courseTitle, int courseDur,
                int courseFee, String courseLevel) {
            this.courseNum = courseNum;
            this.courseTitle = courseTitle;
            this.courseDur = courseDur;
            this.courseFee = courseFee;
            this.courseLevel = courseLevel;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String courseInfo = this.getCourseNum() + ", " + this.getCourseTitle() + ", "
                    + this.getCourseDur() + ", " + this.getCourseFee() + ", " + this.getCourseLevel();
            return courseInfo;
        }

        public String getCourseNum() {
            return this.courseNum;
        }

        public String getCourseTitle() {
            return this.courseTitle;
        }

        public int getCourseDur() {
            return this.courseDur;
        }

        public int getCourseFee() {
            return this.courseFee;
        }

        public String getCourseLevel() {
            return this.courseLevel;
        }

        public void setCourseNum(String courseNum) {
            this.courseNum = courseNum;
        }

        public void setCourseTitle(String courseTitle) {
            this.courseTitle = courseTitle;
        }

        public void setCourseDur(int courseDur) {
            this.courseDur = courseDur;
        }

        public void setCourseTitle(int courseFee) {
            this.courseFee = courseFee;
        }

        public void setCourseLevel(String courseLevel) {
            this.courseLevel = courseLevel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I was looking for. I look forward to the day I'll be able to better understand what is going on. I will study this code and hopefully grow to understand it. Good on ya, mate. Cheers

Comment: @Spud, `It is exactly what I was looking for.` - does this mean you have given up solving it on your own? I was wondering how long it would be until you decided to eat the fish given to you instead of learning to fish on your own. Don't forget as mentioned this solution breaks the default functionality of the combo box. Everybody that posts answers like this always forgets to mention that part of the solution.

Comment: @camickr I am desperately trying to learn to fish on my own. It's not that I don't try, and I appreciate your efforts to push me to finding a solution. I spend countless hours trying things out and don't come here before trying to solve things on my own. Cheers

Comment: @Spud, the renderer code you posted looks nothing like the simple renderer code I gave you yeseteday in the provided link. My point is to more carefully read the answers you are given so that you don't need to repeat the question.